# i18n rails get translations from two different yml files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am using tolk for translation, but tolk takes all my values from `en.yml` and dumpes them in `es.yml`    overwriting the existing content .

There are some stuff i don't want to be overwritten , so when i am searching for the es translations, i want rails to look in both `es.yml` and `es.defaults.yml`

( and so, i can keep isolated what i generate with tolk, and what remais the same )

Is there a way i can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails loads every file in the `config/locales/` directory, so it will probably already work like you're suggesting. You can even organize it further than that, according to the I18n Guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#organization-of-locale-files

However, I think that with duplicate key structures, Rails will probably override the values of the earlier loaded (sorted by file name) locale file with the values of the later loaded file. So please try to avoid duplicate keys.